# What is the point of using spring transaction while we have database level transaction?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-transactions

What is the point of using spring transaction while we have database level transaction ?

If you use mysql, oracle or any other db in java, they provide methods to make things inside transaction then why spring transaction if I can do transaction using java DB driver methods ?

Comment: More details are here http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html

Comment: The point is to let Spring start, join, commit and rollback database-level transactions automatically for you by just annotating classes/methods with `@Transactional`. And to handle them the same way, whether you use JDBC, Hibernate, JPA, or an XA-compliant transaction manager.

Comment: so shall i use both or either of those two?

Comment: They're the same thing. Using a Spring transaction ends up using a database transaction. It's just much easier to let Spring handle it for you, in a purely declarative way: "I want everything in that methods to be done in a transaction, so I annotate it with @Transactional"

Answer (score 0):

It's another layer of abstraction over the database transaction API.  So if you wanted to use multiple databases with global transactions, Spring would allow you to do this.  While I have never done it, I believe it would allow you to use DB2 and Hibernate together, for example.

Generally, what I've found is, if a feature is available in Spring, it's because there is a use case for it.  They don't just put things into the framework without a reason.

Also, Spring provides declarative transaction demarcation, which produces more readable and maintainable Java code. The declarative approach lets us change the transaction strategy easily, without changing the code.

The Declarative transaction management approach allows you to manage the transaction with the help of configuration instead of hard coding in your source code. This means that you can separate transaction management from the business code. You only use annotations or XML based configuration to manage the transactions

We used Spring AOP along with Hibernate using this transaction strategy  Here is an example, [Spring AOP transaction mangement with Hibernate](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-aop-transaction-management-in-hibernate/).

Comment: Can I understand like this, Spring just wrapped another layer of db interaction over JTA about the transaction? Spring doesn't provide any extra ability to manipulate the transaction on the application level?